# Greek Mythology symbols and their fair use

Tags: copyright, legal-terms

I'm making a video game that I will sell on an online website. I want to implement some references to greek mythology like symbols. Am I allowed to implement them and sell my game?

Comment: Who created these symbols, and when?

Comment: "greek" should be "Greek".

Answer (score 1):

You have to consider both copyright and trademark.

Copyright protection generally lasts for 70 years from the death of the author, though the details vary from one country to the next.  Any symbols that were created in ancient Greece are free from copyright protection.  If the symbols you're interested in were created in the last century or so then you'll need to look more closely at whether they are protected by copyright.

Trademark protection may apply if someone else is already using your intended symbols to sell something, especially if the thing being sold is similar to your game.  This also depends on the jurisdiction and even the market, making trademark a fairly complicated matter for a product that is available globally.